# Old Fantasy Series about a group of college roleplayers who are transported to the alternate world of their professor

Tags: story-identification, books

The stories were based on a group of college roleplayers who were transported to the alternate world of their professor (the Dungeon Master). There were multiple books in the series.

My memory of the stories has faded but I can remember slavers and the college kids introducing gunpowder to this new world.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  You might also go through the list of Story Identification points and see if any of those points jog any memories in regards to the series: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Joel Rosenbeg's *[Guardians of the Flame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Flame)*

[image: Book Cover - Guardians of the Flame omnibus]

> **Guardians of the Flame** is a long-running series by author Joel Rosenberg and is arguably his best-known work. The series is about a group of college students who participate in a fantasy role-playing game, and are magically transported to the world of the game by their gamemaster.
>
> The first book, *The Sleeping Dragon*, focuses on the former students struggling to survive in the world of the game. The series progresses with the students choosing to live in the 'game world' and forming their own community, which is in part based on opposition to the ubiquitous slave trade.
>
> In the later books, the focus shifts from efforts to destroy the slave trade and on to various characters dealing with the changes in the fantasy world wrought by the former students (now mostly 40-somethings). The final three books shift focus to a new set of protagonists, relegating the 'Other Siders' to supporting cast and cameo appearances.

....

> **Louis 'Lou' Riccetti** is one of the students. Originally, after reaching This Side, he was a somewhat powerful wizard called Aristobulous. He gave up his wizardly powers to revive his comrade Ahira from death, promising to use his skills as an engineering student to technologically revolutionize This Side. He succeeds to an amazing degree, introducing things such as gunpowder and the telegraph. He is known as the Engineer and has begun to train students to go into the world and create. To date, he is still alive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response.

Comment: It was a favorite of mine as a child.